# Prevent model update before save

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-model

I go the list view page click on edit of any element. Change something on textbox and click cancel. This navigates to list view but the entry is now updated even without me saving.

**Route**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp.Group', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $rxStatusTagsProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/group/list', {
                templateUrl: 'group/templates/list_view.html',
                controller: "GroupListCtrl"
            });
            $routeProvider.when('/group/edit/:id', {
                templateUrl: 'group/templates/edit.html',
                controller: "GroupEditCtrl"
            });
        }]);

    //http://localhost:5000/groups/list
}());
```

**Ctrl**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('myApp.Group')
        .controller("GroupListCtrl", function ($scope, GroupService) {
            $scope.groups = GroupService.list();
        })
        .controller("GroupEditCtrl", function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, GroupService) {
            var id = $routeParams.id;

            $scope.id = id;
            $scope.entry = GroupService.get(id);

            $scope.save = function (entry) {
                GroupService.save(entry);
                $location.path('/group/list');
            };

        })

}());
```

**Service**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('myApp.Group')
        .service('GroupService', function ($http, $location, $rootScope) {

            var uid = 1,
                listData = [
                    {"id": 1, "name": "System Admins",  "description": "Lorem ipsuem"},
                    {"id": 2, "name": "OS Admin",     "description": "Lorem ipsuem"}
                ];

            this.get = function (id) {
                return listData[id - 1];
            };
        });
}());
```

**Edit tmpl**

```
<form method="post" ng-submit="groupForm.$valid && save(group)" name="groupForm" novalidate>
    <rx-form-fieldset>
        <rx-form-item label="Name">
            <input type="text" ng-model="entry.name" name="groupName" required autofocus ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="30"/>
            <div ng-show="groupForm.groupName.$dirty && groupForm.groupName.$invalid">
                <span class="error" ng-show="groupForm.groupName.$error.required">Required!</span>
                <span class="error" ng-show="groupForm.groupName.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
                <span class="error" ng-show="groupForm.groupName.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
            </div>
        </rx-form-item>
        <rx-form-item label="Description">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="30" ng-model="entry.description" name="groupDescription" required ></textarea>
            <div ng-show="groupForm.groupDescription.$dirty && groupForm.groupDescription.$invalid">
                <span class="error" ng-show="groupForm.groupDescription.$error.required">Required!</span>
            </div>
        </rx-form-item>
        <rx-button toggle-msg="Loading..." default-msg="Save" type="submit" ></rx-button>
        <rx-button ng-controller="redirectCtrl" default-msg="Cancel" ng-click="back('group/list')"></rx-button>
    </rx-form-fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You need make a copy of your model. On reset click you can restore the copied model to the changed one

Answer (score 3):

I think you need create a copy of your model in case you need to restore original state when cancel is invoked. To make a copy of your model you do a copy of the model in a separate JS object in the scope like following:

```
$scope.master= angular.copy($scope.entry);
```

Once you have cancel clicked you can restore master object into model to discard the changes:

```
angular.copy($scope.master, $scope.entry);
```

In case you want to look at API reference here is it for you https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: anyway to prevent two way binding

Comment: and do you mean groups or group

Comment: it should be your model name

Comment: So you basically editing $scope.entry right? If yes see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save the old data when you click on element to open the model and when cancel is clicked you need to assigned old data back to your `entry` object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$rollbackViewValue()`. [Angular Docs for ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)